# Constructing Volatility Smile from Implied Volatility & Delta

Tags: options, volatility, implied

I have **implied volatility** data for call and put options (expiring in 1 month from any given date) for a particular stock. In addition, I have the **delta** for the options.

However, I have no information about the spot price of the stock or the strike price of the options.

How do I draw a **volatility smile** from the given data?

Answer (score 1):

First off, volatility smiles are often drawn over a delta space.

Since you're asking, I'll assume you're trying to draw a volatility smile over strike prices, log moneyness, or some similar metric. If you have *neither* the spot price *nor* any strike prices associated with your data, I don't believe it's possible to back out both of those values. Not absolutely certain, but I assume there must be infinite possibilities. If you just had the spot price, you could back out all the strikes with ease.

Comment: The spot price is publicly available on yahoo/google finance or even the company website.

One can back out the strikes and then plot the smile using strikes on X-axis and implied vol on Y-axis.

Comment: OP explicitly stated he does not have the spot price. You can't even be sure he's talking about equity data.

Comment: However, given delta and associated volatilities, it is possible to convert those strikes to percentages of the forward

Comment: @Bram yes, I agree.

Comment: @nsw, I believe "options on a particular stock" indicates that the context is equity options.